# Why is my attempt to submit my form returning "Not a valid datetime value"

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, flask

I created a form that allowed a user to select a desired date and time but when the form is submitted I got this error message

```
Not a valid datetime value
```

I tried including the desired format or the standard datetime format but I got the same result

```
#Form.py
class AddPostForm(FlaskForm):
    post_title = StringField('Share Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = StringField('Description', validators=[DataRequired()])
    share_date = DateTimeField('Share Date', validators=[DataRequired()])


#views.py

@posts_blueprint.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_post():
    form = AddPostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            new_post = Post(form.post_title.data, form.description.data, 
                            current_user.id, form.share_date)


            db.session.add(new_post)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('New shared Item, {}added!'.format(new_post.post_title), 
                  'success')
            return redirect(url_for('posts.user_posts'))
       else:
           flash_errors(form)
           flash('ERROR! Recipe was not added.', 'error')

   return render_template('add_post.html', title='Add Item', form=form)


#add_post.html
{% from "_form_macros.html" import render_errors %}
{% import "bootstrap/utils.html" as utils %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}

<div class="content-section">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h2>Add a New Post</h2>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <form action="{{ url_for('posts.add_post') }}" method="post" 
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {{ form.csrf_token }}
<div class="form-group row">
  <legend for="post_title" class="col-form-legend col-sm-3">Title</legend>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="post_title" 
    name="post_title" placeholder="Enter Post title...">
    {{ render_errors(form.post_title) }}
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <legend for="description" class="col-form-legend col-sm- 
  3">Description</legend>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" 
    name="description" placeholder="Enter post description...">
    {{ render_errors(form.description) }}
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
<legend for="share_date" class="col-form-legend col-sm-3">Sharing 
Date</legend>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="share_date" 
  name="share_date" placeholder="Sharing Date...">
  {{ render_errors(form.share_date) }}
 </div>
 </div>

<div class="center">
  <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add post</button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The user should be able to input the desired date and time and submit the form successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a conflict between what your database expects and what your form is sending.
Try looking at what date format you are using in your model and also try printing out the form data to the console to see what it gives you.
Also try looking at the documentation for the wtforms to see what date type it uses and match that to the date field in your database model.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check the format of the entered date matches what the `DateTimeField` is expecting.

See: [DateTimeField Docs](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.DateTimeField)

Where the default format is: `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

If you know the format you're submitting, you can provide it when you create the field object:

```
    share_date = DateTimeField('Share Date', format='your-format', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Comment: I tried your recommendation but got the same flash-error. The date/time appear in the browser like this:   `dd/mm/yy--:--` and I formatted the field like this:                                                           `share_date = DateTimeField('Share Date', format='%d-%m-%y %H:%M', validators=[DataRequired()])`

Comment: After reading a bit more about it, you will want to switch to the WTForms `DateTimeLocal` field (`from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateTimeField`) to get the correct `<input type="datetime-local"...`.

Then, the default normalised datetime-local format is: `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm`. You can change this using the `pattern` attribute on the `input` to change this if you like ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local)). 

In short, your formats still won't match. You're expecting `%d-%m-%y %H:%M`, but the form is submitting `%y-%m-%dT%H:%M`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `type="datetime-local"` in you template you need to  first makeing sure you're importing `DateTimeLocalField` not `DateTimeField` and then in my case i was also imported incorrectly:

```
from wtforms.fields import DateTimeLocalField
```

Instead of:

```
from wtforms import DateTimeLocalField
```

**Its now working fine and not returning None to BackEnd!**

[image: Modern_Datetime_Filde]

## template.html

```
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
  {{ form.dateTime(class="form-control", type="datetime-local") }}
  { form.dateTime.label(class="form-label") }}
</div>
```

## myapp.py

```
from wtforms.fields import DateTimeLocalField
...

class PostEditor_form(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Enter The Title')
    dateTime = DateTimeLocalField(
        'Date Time', 
        format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", # secend needeed or its returning None
        default= datetime.utcnow
        )
    SendPost = SubmitField('Post')


@app.route("/Upload", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@flask_login.login_required
def PostEditor(country):
    ...

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        dateTime = form.dateTime.data

form = PostEditor_form()

Image_path = ''
btn_sendpost = ''

print(form.dateTime.data)
# 2022-08-28 21:29:42.294706

#*  Upload-Image & Send-Data
if form.validate_on_submit():
    title = form.title.data
    bodyContent = form.bodyContent.data
    dateTime = form.dateTime.data        

    #* Upload Image Clicked
    if form.UploadImage.data:
        pfile = request.files['postImgae']
        filename = secure_filename(pfile.filename)
        Image_path = os.path.join("image/postImage/", f"{current_user.username}{datetime.utcnow().timestamp()}{filename}") 
        pfile.save(os.path.join(file_dir , 'static/'+Image_path))
        # flush_msg(message='Image Uploaded!', type='success')
        btn_sendpost = form.SendPost( class_="btn btn-primary col-3")

    #* Send Data
    if form.SendPost.data: 
        # Send to another api
        ...

        # Claering Data
        form.title.data = ''
        form.bodyContent.data = ''
        form.dateTime.data = ''
        
        flush_msg(message='Posted Successfully....! )', type='success')
    
if form.errors: print(form.errors)

return render_template(
    'Post-Editor.html',
    form=form, btn_sendpost=btn_sendpost)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I fixed it by changing the format of DateLocalField in my form to this:

```
outage_start = DateTimeLocalField(
        label="Outage Date",
        format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M",
        validators=[Optional()],
    )
```